# Can a database created in MS SQL Server Express be exported to MS SQL standard?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

As the title states, *can a databse created in MS SQL Server Express be exported to MS SQL standard?*

For the inent of the question, the version in question is 2008.

Comment: Yes. SQL Server doesn't care what *edition* the databases come from, as long as they come from a supported version (meaning you can't restore a database that was created in SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Both products are part of Microsoft's standard SQL platform. Simply backup your database on the SQL Express platform and restore the backup on the SQL Standard platform.

It really is that simple. About the only possible issue I can think of that will make it more than a few mouse-clicks or a couple lines of T-SQL is that you will need to specify new locations for the .mdf and .ldf files during the restore process. And that's not exactly rocket science to figure out.